# How should I structure those nested if statements?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, boolean-logic

I have a nested if like this:

```
  if (condition 1)
    if (condition 2)
        statement
    end
else
    if (condition 3)
       statement
    end
end
```

The two statements are the same.
Written like this, it goes to condition 3 only when condition 1 is not satisfied, while if condition 2 is not satisfied it interrupts the execution of the statements. Instead, I want my code to skip to condition 3 also in the case only condition 2 is not satisfied (and condition 1 it is).
Should I use any "break" or "switch" or do I need just to change the disposition of my nested if?

Edit: Basically I want that if condition 1 is satisfied but condition 2 is not it skips to condition 3.
In other words, I would like that condition 3 is verified if:
1) condition 1 is not satisfied;
2) condition 1 is satisfied but condition 2 is not satisfied.

Comment: Draw a [Karnaugh map](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=karnaugh+map&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ElmeVcb4GKXV7Qbtir3YAw); when `statement` should be run, based on whether each of the three conditions is true or false, should then become clear.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is (note that in matlab you don't need parentheses for the if condition):

```
if (condition1 && condition2) || condition3
  statement
end
```

Comment: You don't even need the parens, here, because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: You're right. I added these parentheses for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about the logic, when to enter `statement`:

1. if condition1 and condition2 are true.
2. if condition1 is false and condition3 is true.
3. if condition1 is true, condition2 is false and condition3 is true.

Now we can put everything into one if clause by using the logical OR `||` and the logical AND `&&`.
We can also combine the 1. and 3. term to

4. if condition1 is true and condition2 or condition 3 is true

Together, this gives:

```
if (condition1 && (condition2 || condition3)) || (~condition1 && condition3)
    statement
end
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. `A && (B || C) || (~A && C)` is equivalent to `A && B || A && C || ~A && C`, which simplifies to `A && B || C`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your suggestion. They really helped me to find the answer. At the end I solved my problem doing:

```
if (condition 1) && (condition 2)
    statement
else
    if (condition 3)
       statement
    end
end
```

Comment: This solution is error prone. If you ever change the statement you have to remember to change in both places